# AppEngine Content-Encoding header doesn't appear

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, response-headers, content-encoding

I'm trying to send a compressed file through AppEngine, my function is

```
func handleWebGLRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)

    blobKey, err := blobstore.BlobKeyForFile(c, "/gs/<path>/WebGL.datagz")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Problem: cannot find WebGL.data")
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "blah/blah/application/octet-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
    blobstore.Send(w, blobKey)
}
```

The file is sent, the content-type appears correctly in the response header with "blah/blah/application/octet-stream", but Content-Encoding is never in the response header, which (I think) is the cause of other issues I'm having.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

(In case it matters - I'm using chrome inspector to view the response headers, and here it is, source not parsed

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: blah/blah/application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 06:50:09 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=1)

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control this header, the servers actually try to serve gzipped content as frequently as possible, as long as they're confident the browser will support it.

> #### [How do I serve compressed content?](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#compression)
>
> Google App Engine does its best to serve gzipped content to browsers that support it. Taking advantage of this scheme is automatic and requires no modifications to applications.

Comment: That makes sense. To add to the answer, on Cloud Storage you *can* control Content-Encoding (files on Cloud Storage can be put in zipped or non-zipped state and will stay that way, you must set the metadata yourself including Content-Encoding). it's possible to redirect to it, but in most situations that will create cross-domain policy issues